# ¿Como colocar las variables de entorno automaticamente en flask?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, flask

soy nuevo en python y flask y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma en la que automaticamente al correr 'flask run' en la consola se coloquen la misma variable 'FLASK_APP=loquesea.py' hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Te recomiendo este blog de Niguel Ginberg, el te explica muchas cosas interesantes si estas iniciando con flask.:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: se debe instalar pip python-dotenv dentro del proyecto para que se ejecute el archivo de configuracion .nombre donde estan las variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ingeniero Jose Zolano nos recomienda crear un archivo  .flaskenv en la raiz del proyecto, dentro del archivo .flaskenv  colocar la variable 'FLASK_APP=loquesea.py' y cada vez que ejecutes flask run la variable se ejecuta automáticamente. link de referencia:
https://j2logo.com/tutorial-flask-leccion-7-parametros-de-configuracion-proyecto/